# Qt - Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() with an enum class type

Tags: c++, qt, enum-class

Is there a way to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() with enum class types? I know old enums work but what about these new, strongly typed, ones? Can't find anything regarding this problem elsewhere. I'm using the latest Qt version available.

Example:

```
enum Foo
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)
QVariant var = Foo::A; // works fine

enum class Bar
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Bar)
QVariant var = Bar::X; // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because when you use a plain old `enum`:

```
enum Foo { A, B, C };
QVariant var = Foo::A;
```

the compiler in fact uses the following constructor to build up your `var` instance:

```
QVariant(const QVariant& other);
```

And going further, the `other` instance is created using the following non-explicit constructor:

```
QVariant(int val);
```

This is possible, because old `enums` **can** be treated as integral values.

To sum up, this is what the compiler sees and does *behind the scene*:

```
int temp = Foo::A;
QVariant var = QVariant(temp);
```

As you know, `enum class`es **CAN NOT** be treated as integral values without an explicit cast. Thus, the compiler cannot implicitly convert your type to `int`, and invoke a matching constructor (to be precise: the best candidate from all available constructors). That is, there is a predefined set of constructors `QVariant` offers. You cannot add a new one using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro.

To use `QVariant` with your own type, you should rather use [`QVariant::fromValue(const T& t)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#fromValue) function:

```
enum class Foo { A, B, C };
QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(Foo::A);
```

or alternatively:

```
enum class Foo { A, B, C };
QVariant var;
var.setValue(Foo::A);
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but how do I extract the enum value from the QVariant object? I could use the toInt() method before, but now not so much.

Comment: If I try using `QVariant::fromValue()` I get the error "Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system".

Comment: Extract enum class value from `QVariant` (assuming it was registered with `Q_ENUM(Foo)`):  `Foo foo = var.value<Foo>();`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Q_ENUM](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) which was added in Qt 5.5:

```
enum class Bar
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
};
Q_ENUM(Bar)

QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(Bar::X);
```

Comment: Note that this only works for enum classes defined inside a class deriving from QObject not for globally defined enum classes.

Comment: If you're using a namespace for a globally defined enum you can use `Q_ENUM_NS` which was added in Qt 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Tried proposed solution using `QVariant::fromValue`, but kept getting compiler errors of type:

> Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to
>   make it known to Qt's meta-object system

My workround was to explicitly cast the enum values to `int` when passing them onto a function requiring a `QVariant` type, in my case when adding a `QComboBox` item, and then casting it back to my enum class type at value retrieval.

In context of the original question, this would be something akin to:

```
enum class Foo { A, B, C };

// Elsewhere, adding item to QComboBox.
m_comboBox->addItem(tr("A"), static_cast<int>(Foo::A));

// Value retrieval from QComboBox item, somewhere else.
const auto foo { static_cast<Foo>(m_comboBox->currentData().value<int>()) };
```